# add column with incrementing integer to multiple csv files

Tags: shell, csv, awk, cat

I have a directory with thousands of csv files, each with 64 columns and 700+ lines. I would like to combine for importing into database tables.

Using cat, combining the files is no problem. However, each file represents a separate event, so when querying the database I would like to be able to extract just the lines from an individual file.

Is there a way to add an incrementing integer to each file before combing them?

for example:

log_file1

- a, b, c, d,...
- a, b, c, d,...
- a, b, c, d,...

log_file2

- a, b, c, d,...
- a, b, c, d,...
- a, b, c, d,...

to

log_file1

- 1, a, b, c, d...
- 1, a, b, c, d...
- 1, a, b, c, d...

log_file2

- 2, a, b, c, d...
- 2, a, b, c, d...
- 2, a, b, c, d...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk, you could write:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {count++} {print count "," $0}' *.csv
```

That increments the "count" variable when the first record of each file is being processed.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk '{print ARGIND "," $0}' *.csv
```